# Endpoint protection configuration via @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

While trying to recreate a sample from a book demonstrating how to restrict access to an endpoint, I'm getting an unexpected behavior - an admin with a permitting role is disallowed access:

```
    $ curl -X POST \
>   'http://localhost:9090/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=admin&password=password2' \
>   -H 'authorization: Basic d2ViYXBwOndlYnNlY3JldA==' \
>   -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
>   -d '"category":"test","document":"this is a test document"'
    {"access_token":"6d149c21-6a48-41e8-885d-d6da70648b49","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":42860,"scope":"read,write,trust"}

$ curl -X GET \
>   'http://localhost:9090/resource?access_token=6d149c21-6a48-41e8-885d-d6da70648b49' \
>   -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \

{"timestamp":1508464945487,"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","exception":"org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException","message":"Access Denied","path":"/resource"}
```

Here are the relevant classes:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();   
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user1").password("password1").roles("USER")
        .and().withUser("admin").password("password2").roles("ADMIN");
    }

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll().and()
        // default protection for all resources (including /oauth/authorize)
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN");
        // ... more configuration, e.g. for form login
   }

}
```

---

```
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("webapp").secret("websecret").authorizedGrantTypes("password")
                .scopes("read,write,trust");
    }



}
```

---

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableResourceServer
@RestController
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class OauthServerApplication {


    @RequestMapping("/resource")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public String resourceEndpoint() {
        return "This resource is protected by the resource server.";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OauthServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

The goal is to have only `admin`user to be able to access the resource endpoint, while the regular user `user1`is to be denied access.

N.B.: the below stanza is actually something I added:

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll().and()
        // default protection for all resources (including /oauth/authorize)
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN");
        // ... more configuration, e.g. for form login
   }
```

as its absence produces the following during resource acquisition attempt (2nd request):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body onload='document.f.username.focus();'>
        <h3>Login with Username and Password</h3>
        <form name='f' action='/login' method='POST'>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>User:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='text' name='username' value=''>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='password' name='password'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='2'>
                        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <input name="_csrf" type="hidden" value="1cbdad0b-181e-496c-aed0-eb633b29eab7" />
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

After enabling web security log, as some of the commentators suggested, like so:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

.....

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.debug(true);
    } 
...}
```

here's the partial resulting server log from the 2 requests:

```
2017-10-20 07:17:27.836  WARN 12728 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.a.web.builders.WebSecurity       : 

********************************************************************
**********        Security debugging is enabled.       *************
**********    This may include sensitive information.  *************
**********      Do not use in a production system!     *************
********************************************************************


2017-10-20 07:17:29.116  INFO 12728 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
2017-10-20 07:17:29.180  INFO 12728 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-10-20 07:17:29.186  INFO 12728 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'configurationPropertiesRebinder' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2017-10-20 07:17:29.187  INFO 12728 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'refreshEndpoint' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2017-10-20 07:17:29.187  INFO 12728 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'restartEndpoint' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2017-10-20 07:17:29.187  INFO 12728 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'environmentManager' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2017-10-20 07:17:29.188  INFO 12728 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'refreshScope' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2017-10-20 07:17:29.189  INFO 12728 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'environmentManager': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager]
2017-10-20 07:17:29.197  INFO 12728 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'restartEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.restart:name=restartEndpoint,type=RestartEndpoint]
2017-10-20 07:17:29.202  INFO 12728 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'refreshScope': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh:name=refreshScope,type=RefreshScope]
2017-10-20 07:17:29.207  INFO 12728 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinder': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties:name=configurationPropertiesRebinder,context=6f7923a5,type=ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder]
2017-10-20 07:17:29.211  INFO 12728 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'refreshEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.endpoint:name=refreshEndpoint,type=RefreshEndpoint]
2017-10-20 07:17:29.338  INFO 12728 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2017-10-20 07:17:29.402  INFO 12728 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 9090 (http)
2017-10-20 07:17:29.406  INFO 12728 --- [           main] c.e.spring.cloud.OauthServerApplication  : Started OauthServerApplication in 6.879 seconds (JVM running for 7.264)
2017-10-20 07:18:20.584  INFO 12728 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-10-20 07:18:20.584  INFO 12728 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-10-20 07:18:20.600  INFO 12728 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 16 ms
2017-10-20 07:18:20.606  INFO 12728 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] Spring Security Debugger                 : 

************************************************************

Request received for POST '/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=user1&password=password1':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@5ace935e

servletPath:/oauth/token
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:9090
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 54
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
cache-control: no-cache
origin: chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
authorization: Basic d2ViYXBwOndlYnNlY3JldA==
postman-token: cd55952b-6c6f-6101-8f24-3942dee9b06a
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8
cookie: JSESSIONID=F4526A8B6FD15FD35D3D84D25E2C3898


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  BasicAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************


2017-10-20 07:20:18.604  INFO 12728 --- [nio-9090-exec-4] Spring Security Debugger                 : 

************************************************************

Request received for GET '/resource?access_token=5466dfff-f088-4097-8db9-4ed07f0b80a0':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@5ace935e

servletPath:/resource
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:9090
connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
postman-token: 394b6610-1d18-eec7-338b-ab1de65cfeeb
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8
cookie: JSESSIONID=F4526A8B6FD15FD35D3D84D25E2C3898


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CsrfFilter
  LogoutFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************


2017-10-20 07:20:18.640  INFO 12728 --- [nio-9090-exec-4] Spring Security Debugger                 : 

************************************************************

New HTTP session created: 1D899B6306F970E097CE746030A28E4A

Call stack: 

    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.Logger.info(Logger.java:44)
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugRequestWrapper.getSession(DebugFilter.java:166)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:240)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:240)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache.saveRequest(HttpSessionRequestCache.java:59)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.sendStartAuthentication(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:133)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.invokeWithWrappedRequest(DebugFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


************************************************************
```

When I comment out the `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")` annotation on top of the resource endpoint, the resource request correctly displays "This resource is protected by the resource server."  Also a breakpoint placed in there gets triggered.  Re-enabling the @PreAuthorize annotation seems to introduce the improper behavior and skips the breakpoint.  Where in the surrounding Spring infrastructure could I place the breakpoint to research deeper this effect of `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")` annotation?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the book articulate on how the rest endpoint is meant to know that token represents that user?  When I've seen this done with JWT, Spring is able to derive a SecurityContext from the JWT itself.  That token, however, doesn't look like a JWT (it doesn't appear to be in the correct format for a JWT).  What's not clear to me is how the request context is expected to take what looks to be a uuid and derive that the SecurityContext is one with an Admin role?

Comment: @EdH: it just lists the steps and shows that with the configuration I listed the OAuth token produced via ```@EnableAuthorizationServer``` during the 1st request, in the 2nd one is permitting to see the String contents of the resource exposed via ```@EnableResourceServer``` & ```@RestController``` only to the admin user and not to the regular user.  They don't discuss JWT.  In my case it seems to disallow them both.

Comment: OK, I neglected to see that the authServer and resource server are the same process.  So, perhaps it can access the SecurityContext using that uuid, as it's likely stored internally.

Comment: Did you configured CSRF? Could you add Spring Security log with `DEBUG` level set to your question? It shows more informations.

Comment: @dur: No CSRF, at least not explicitly that I'm aware of.  I've posted the logs produced after enabling web security debug as you suggested.

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon: That are the wrong logs. You have to enable `DEBUG` in log configuration not in application configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using **OAuth2**, instead of using the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` you need to use the `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`. For example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().and().cors().disable().csrf().disable().httpBasic().disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(
                    (request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED))
            .accessDeniedHandler(
                    (request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED));
  }
}
```

Now you should be able to use the security methods.

[Here](https://github.com/dzinot/spring-boot-oauth2-jwt) is an implementation for **OAuth2** with **Spring Boot** with custom `UserDetails` service and **JWT token**. The basic implementation is the same.

[Here](https://github.com/dzinot/spring-boot-oauth2-jwt/blob/master/src/main/java/com/kristijangeorgiev/spring/boot/oauth2/jwt/configuration/OAuth2Configuration.java) is the `OAuth2Configuration` for the Authorization Server

[Here](https://github.com/dzinot/spring-boot-oauth2-jwt/blob/master/src/main/java/com/kristijangeorgiev/spring/boot/oauth2/jwt/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.java) is the `WebSecurityConfiguration` for the Authorization Server